# Windows doesn't accept EV signed driver

Tags: windows-10, driver, digital-signature

I have a x64 driver which is digitally signed by Microsoft. It works ok on most of the computers with Windows 10 build 1607. But there are several computers with Windows 10 build 1507, which don't accept it. When driver is starting I have an infamous message shown:

[image: Error message]

Yet the driver starts and works after that. Do I need to sign the driver in a special way?

p.s. No such issues on 1607.

Comment: why do you still use 1507? The 1507 should be only used via LTSB (long supported version) and not as normal edition.

Comment: I don't, the users do.

Comment: tell them to update and block setup of your driver is you detect Build 10240. support for the 1507 ends in May 2017, only LTSB version gets support till 2025

Comment: I doubt this helps to get rid of this message. It's also shown on windows 8.1 build 9600.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I've found what was causing the issue - you must not sign the driver with your EV token certificate when submitting .cab to Microsoft. You must put unsigned driver into cab, and then sing the cab with you EV token. Otherwise you're going to have 2 signatures in the driver binary and Windows will go crazy as I've described.